# Why am I getting NATed when talking to other Docker containers within the same bridge network

Tags: networking, docker, torrent

Hey guys so I'm currently experimenting with a torrent tracker server and two clients using Docker. My setup is that I created my own network called torrent-net.

```
docker network create -d bridge noto-network
```

I then go ahead and create three containers two for clients, one using ctorrent and the other one is custom go code. A third container has the opentracker server installed. The network configuration is as follows:

```
Gateway:
  ip_address: 172.18.0.1/16
Opentracker:
  ip_address: 172.18.0.2/16
  announce_port: 6969
GoCode:
  ip_address: 172.18.0.3/16
  torrent_port: 6881
cTorrent
  ip_address: 172.18.0.4/16
  torrent_port: 2706
```

I start my tracker and ctorrent. When I send a request from my go code to the tracker I get sent back these two peers:

```
- ip: 172.18.0.1
  port: 6881
- ip: 172.18.0.1
  port: 2706
```

I have two questions:

- All three containers are within the same network, so why talking to each other requires NAT?
- As a client how can I know if any of this NAT IP represent me? This in order to avoid trying to talk to myself.